# How to define a BiFunction using a Supplier as Fallback to produce some objects?

Tags: java, function, lambda, generic-programming, supplier

What's wrong with this code? I need to create a factory method which is dependend on a BiFunction to fulfil it's job .

The compiler told me:

```
The method apply(Class<T>, Supplier<I>) 
in the type BiFunction<Class<T>,Supplier<I>,T> 
is not applicable for the arguments (Class<A>, B::new)
```

but B extends A, B::new produces a supplier for B ...

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class BiFunctionTest {

    static interface A {

    }

    static class B implements A {

    }

    static interface C {

    }

    static class D implements C {

    }

    private A a;
    private C c;

    public static <T, I extends T> BiFunctionTest create(
            BiFunction<Class<T>, Supplier<I>, T> fn) {
        BiFunctionTest o = new BiFunctionTest();
        o.a = fn.apply(A.class, B::new);
        o.c = fn.apply(C.class, D::new);
        return o;
    }

    @Test
    public void testBiFunction() {
        BiFunctionTest o = BiFunctionTest.create((i, s) -> s.get());
        assertEquals(B.class, o.a.getClass());
        assertEquals(D.class, o.c.getClass());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generics must match exactly, they are not checked covariantly/contravariantly unless explicitly declared as such. So `Supplier<B>` is not a `Supplier<A>` but is a `Supplier<? extends A>`.

Your signature would then change to the following:

```java
 public static <T, I extends T> BiFunctionTest create(BiFunction<Class<? extends T>, Supplier<? extends I>, T> fn) {...
```

But now for the second problem, the body of your function is not generic in terms of `T` as you are using `A.class` and `B::new`. The generic signature here should be used if the implementation really doesn't depend on those types `A` and `B` but this is not the case.

So dropping the generics from the signature:

```java
public static BiFunctionTest create(BiFunction<Class<? extends A>, Supplier<? extends A>, A> fn) {...
```

we have the appropriate signature for the body you have provided:

```java
    BiFunctionTest o = new BiFunctionTest();
    o.a = fn.apply(A.class, B::new);
    return o;
```

Comment: Updated my codesnipped, because dropping the generics from signature does not solve my problem. The class given as first argument is always a interfaces-class with one or more implementations. The Supplier produces a fallback implementation if there is actually no instance.

Comment: p.s. tried also ``` public static BiFunctionTest create(
            BiFunction<Class<T>, Supplier<? extends T>, T> fn) {
        BiFunctionTest o = new BiFunctionTest();
        o.a = fn.apply(A.class, B::new);
        o.c = fn.apply(C.class, D::new);
        return o;
    } ```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static <T> BiFunctionTest create2(
        BiFunction<Class<T>, Supplier<T>, T> fn) {
    BiFunctionTest o = new BiFunctionTest();
    Supplier<A> u = B::new;
    o.a = fn.apply(A.class, u);
    Supplier<? extends C> u2 = D::new;
    o.c = fn.apply(C.class, u2);
    return o;
}

@Test
public void testBiFunction() {
    BiFunctionTest o = BiFunctionTest.create2((i, s) -> s.get());
    assertEquals(B.class, o.a.getClass());
    assertEquals(D.class, o.c.getClass());
}
```

produces

```
The method apply(Class<T>, Supplier<T>) 
in the type BiFunction<Class<T>,Supplier<T>,T> 
is not applicable for the arguments (Class<BiFunctionTest.A>, Supplier<BiFunctionTest.A>)
```

and

```
The method apply(Class<T>, Supplier<T>) 
in the type BiFunction<Class<T>,Supplier<T>,T> 
is not applicable for the arguments (Class<BiFunctionTest.C>, Supplier<capture#1-of ? extends BiFunctionTest.C>)
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it by adding additional interface, but needs casting .. :/

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class BiFunctionTest {

    static interface A {
    }

    static interface B extends A {
    }

    static class ObjectB implements B {
    }

    static interface C extends A {
    }

    static class ObjectC implements C {
    }

    private B b;
    private C c;

    public static BiFunctionTest create3(
            BiFunction<Class<? extends A>, Supplier<? extends A>, A> fn) {
        BiFunctionTest o = new BiFunctionTest();
        o.b = (B) fn.apply(B.class, ObjectB::new);
        o.c = (C) fn.apply(C.class, ObjectC::new);
        return o;
    }

    @Test
    public void testBiFunction() {
        BiFunctionTest o = BiFunctionTest.create3((i, s) -> s.get());
        assertEquals(ObjectB.class, o.b.getClass());
        assertEquals(ObjectC.class, o.c.getClass());
    }

}
```